# An algebraic stack is an algebraic space if and only if it has the trivial stabilizer group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes, algebraic-stacks

Let $G\to S$ be a smooth affine group scheme over a scheme. Let $U$ be a scheme over $S$ with an action of $G$. Let $[U/G]$ be the quotient stack.
In Alper's note: [Stacks and Moduli](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ejarod/moduli.pdf), there is a result (Corollary 3.6.7) which says:

$[U/G]$ is an algebraic space $\Leftrightarrow$ every point of $U$ has a trivial stabilizer group $\Leftrightarrow$ the action map $G\times U\to U\times U$ is a monomorphism.

I think this theorem just says $[U/G]$ is an algebraic space if and only if the action of $G$ on $U$ is free, is it true?

If it is true, I am confused about the following things.

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$. There is a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action on it. The action is just mapping a point $P$ to $-P$. This action is not free, it has 4 fixed points. However, $C/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{P}^{1}$ which is a scheme and therefore is an algebraic space. It seems to contradict with the above theorem. Can you tell me where I made a mistake?

Also, I wonder if we remove the "affine" condition and just require the group scheme is smooth, is the theorem still true?

Comment: Elliptic curves aren't affine …?

Comment: Good question. The problem is that you didn't take the stack quotient. For example, the trivial action of Z/2Z on the spectrum of a field k has stack quotient B(Z/2Z).

Comment: ...Following your logic, free group on two letters and ring of commutative polynomials over rationals are isomorphic, because they are both countably infinite sets. (If you forget stack structure on the quotient stack and only remember underlying functor of points, of course you will always get an algebraic space!)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I know the result know. Basically, I forgot the stack structure